# How to REALLY delete a photo using Apple Photos when image is outside library?

Tags: photos.app

I have all my photos in a per year folder under

> $HOME/Pictures

I manage my photos using Finder, Lightroom and many other tools.
So I want to keep my image in a classic folder, not within a Photos library.

So when I imported my photos within Photos, I unchecked the *Copy items to the Photos library* [image: Importing option]

I have imported my photos within Photos. But when I delete one photo with command + backspace, the photo is not deleted from the hard drive.
It is put in a *Recently Deleted* folder and hidden from the image library.

And if I click on the *Delete All* button, the image no more appears in Photos but is still on the hard drive at the exact same place.

**How to delete a photo using Photos?**

And on top of these, if I delete a photos using another tools, like Finder, Photos has no command to *refresh* and remove the deleted photos from the Photos library.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Great question, and well stated. I use some of the same apps as you, and find the logic (?) used in Photos to be inscrutable (not to mention annoying!).

Comment: I ended with using only Photos App. Which is what Apple wants you to do in the first place. Using only their product.